# Closed form of integral $\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy\frac{ \text{Li}_{k}(\exp(-(y-\frac{\xi }{2})^2))}{\exp (2 \xi y)-1}$

Tags: integration, special-functions, polylogarithms, specific-calculation

How could one calculate the closed form solution of this integral:
$\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy\frac{ \text{Li}_{k}(\exp(-(y-\frac{\xi }{2})^2))}{\exp (2 \xi  y)-1}$

Here the integral is understood as principal value integral. The $\text{Li}_{k}$ is the $k$th order polylog function. $\xi>0$ is a real parameter. I was trying to use contour integral in the complex $y$ plane, but it seems the function does not fulfill Jordan's Lemma. As a result, simply summing over the residues gives a diverging answer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

PS: Even if general closed-form expression for any $k$ may not be possible, an answer for a specific $k$ value will also be appreciated!

Comment: What is $\xi$, a real number?

Comment: Yes, $\xi>0$ is a real parameter.

Comment: even for $k=1$, when the polylog is a log, there does not seem to be a closed form answer.